# Extracting data in child and sub child nodes using JSoup with separator

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am currently trying to parse the below HTML string in Java using Jsoup library

```
<div class="external container">
<div class="description">
    <h3>Some Description</h3>
    <p>
Some more description</p>
    <p>
        <strong>Description Subheader</strong>
    </p>
    <p>
Description sub header text</p>
    <p>
        <strong>Features 1:</strong>
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>d
            <ul>
                <li>d1</li>
                <li>d2</li>
                <li>d3</li>
                <li>d4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p>
        <strong>Features 2:</strong>
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to extract entire description in one String and each Feature is separate Strings. I have tried

```
(String) xpath.evaluate(By.xpath(xpath), doc,XPathConstants.STRING);
```

but it returns entire content in one string which makes it hard to differentiate. Also, I tried,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
        Elements mainEle= doc.body().children();
        for(Element element : mainEle)
        {
            Elements elements = element.select("*");
            for (Element element2 : elements) {
                features=features+element2.ownText();
            }
        }
```

But this too returns the entire content in one String.

I could write xpaths/css and extract single elements. However, the problem is that I have multiple HTML Strings to parse and each have a different combination/set of features and some have description in `'<p>'` tag tag while do not have description container.

I would simply like to parse the data and be able to differentiate each String using JSoup library

For the example above, I should get 3 Strings

description string should return -

> Some Description | Some more description | Description Subheader |
>   Description sub header text

Feature1 should return -

> Features 1: | a | b | c | d : d1,d2,d3,d4

Feature2 should return -

> Features 2: | a | b | c

Comment: Please give the description string you want to build for this example.

Comment: @Tashi I have updated the question